# Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Id' in table Entity1' is specified more than once

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

Idea is to use nameof for foreign key, because if change property name compiler will catch this so I will never forget to change foreign key dependency

```
public class Entity1 {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OtherId { get; set; }

    [Foreign Key(nameof(OtherId))]
    public virtual Entity2 Entity { get; set; }
}
   public Entity2 {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Error from subject is getting when I try to update database from migration.
Am I doing anything wrong here ?
Regards,

Comment: Your `OtherId` also has the name `Id` probably? I'd suggest naming your ids something like: `Entity1Id` and `Entity2Id`. Should solve the problem and makes your code more readable.

Comment: @FeRaaC yes Entity1 has own primary key called Id. But in database I must see column called OtherId.

Comment: Can you do `[Foreign Key(nameof(Entity2.OtherId))]` ?

Comment: @RobinBennett Entity2 don't have column OtherId, has only Id which is primary key. Will update code.

Answer (score 0):

you already have a property in the same class with that name. try changing the foreign key name such as:

```
[ForeignKey("name of foreign key here")]
  public virtual Entity2 Entity { get; set; }
```

see:

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I need to use nameof

Comment: @DanijelBoksan you cant use the same name of a property/column already defined in the same class. you also dont need the "OtherId" property

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public class Entity1 
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Entity2")]
  public int Entity2ID { get; set; }

  public virtual Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: where is nameof for foreign key?

Comment: you don't need to specify a foreign key, the compiler will detect it

Comment: In your example [ForeignKey("Entity2")] Entity2 is name of Entity or variable name of Entity2 ?

Comment: the name of variable